# Unable to edit any existing entries on EE2 to EE5 upgrade

Tags: channel-entries, entries

**Description of the problem**

I have recently upgraded an EE2 to site up to EE5.3.0 and now I am getting PHP errors when trying to open ** any ** existing entry in the EE CP. The site has no third-party modules installed. Just the standard EE install with default modules etc.

**Error Messages**

```
Exception Caught
HEX color needs to be 6 or 3 digits long
ee/Mexitek/PHPColors/Color.php:41
Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error
    •   #0 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Status/Status.php(116): Mexitek\PHPColors\Color->__construct('blue') 
    •   #1 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Channel/ChannelEntry.php(1176): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Status\Status->getOptionComponent() 
    •   #2 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Channel\ChannelEntry->populateStatus(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade)) 
    •   #3 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/FieldFacade.php(105): call_user_func(Array, Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade)) 
    •   #4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/FieldFacade.php(115): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade->ensurePopulatedDefaults() 
    •   #5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/ContentModel.php(363): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\FieldFacade->setData('closed') 
    •   #6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/ContentModel.php(404): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\ContentModel->setDataOnCustomFields(Array) 
    •   #7 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/ContentModel.php(315): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\ContentModel->initializeCustomFields() 
    •   #8 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Content/ContentModel.php(147): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\ContentModel->usesCustomFields() 
    •   #9 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Model/Channel/ChannelEntry.php(657): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Content\ContentModel->getCustomField('title') 
    •   #10 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Publish/Edit.php(517): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Channel\ChannelEntry->getDisplay(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Channel\Display\DefaultChannelLayout)) 
    •   #11 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Publish\Edit->entry('505') 
    •   #12 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    •   #13 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array) 
    •   #14 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request)) 
    •   #15 index.php(152): require_once('...') 
    •   #15 index.php(152): require_once('...')
```

**Environment Details:**
 - Version: 5.3.0
 - PHP Version 7.2.23
 - MySQL Version 5.7.28
 - OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.1
 - Web Server: Apache

Many thanks in advance for any help on this! :-)

Regards

Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the exp_statuses table and make sure the highlight color has 6 digits, just in case it is blank

Comment: Hi Jez, many thanks for this. I did actually arrive at this solution at little earlier on today (just hadn't got round to updating the post here with the answer etc), however it really is appreciated, and it's definately sorted the issue out.